# How to access custom JSF tags through javascript getElementById

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

I have the following code.

```
<h:form id="Form">
  <div class="pageBody">
    <h:outputLabel id="lbl" styleClass="formLabel" value="#{messages['lable.email']}:" />
    <s:button id="login" label="#{messages['login.button']}" actionBean="#{account}" actionMethod="login" />
  </div>
</h:form>
```

Here is the javascript

```
var obj = document.getElementById("Form:lbl");  //This works
var obj1 = document.getElementById("Form:login"); //This doesnt work
```

Keep in mind that `<s:button>` is a custom JSF Component.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work fine with custom components. Is it a custom component or a composite component? The problem you're having and the presence of JSF 2.0 tag indicates that it's *actually* a [componsite component](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info). For the difference between custom tags, custom components and composite components, check [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-component)

In this answer, I'll assume that it's indeed a composite component.

First of all, JavaScript works with HTML DOM tree, not with JSF component tree. JavaScript namely runs on webbrowser, not on webserver. JSF runs on webserver, produces a bunch of HTML and sends it to webbrowser. The `document.getElementById()` accepts only HTML DOM element ID's.

So, to find out which HTML DOM element ID the `<s:button>` has generated, you should open the JSF page in your webbrowser, do a rightclick and then *View Source* and locate the generated HTML element in the HTML source.

In case of your `<s:button id="login">` composite component which in turn uses for example `<h:commandButton id="button">` in the implementation, then it'll look like something like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="Form:login:button" />
```

A composite component by itself namely an [`NamingContainer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) component, which prepends the IDs like that. The `<h:form>` is also such a component. This enables you to use multiple composite components inside the same parent container.

You should use exactly *that* ID in your JavaScript function.

```
var button = document.getElementById("Form:login:button");
```

Comment: Thanks I did a inspect in the chrome. The button has its own xhtml. I just have to put the id of the <span id = "loginBtnMain"> and works